# Can you open a user specified file in read/write mode with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, filestream, local-storage

I'm having some problems in Silverlight getting a certain behavior when it comes to saving and opening files.

What we'd like:
We'd like to prompt a user to open a file when the Silverlight application launches.  We'd then read any information from this file and use it to set the state of our application.  We'd also like to respond to a user clicking 'save' and write all of the changes in state back to that original file.

What we've tried:

Isolated storage: does what we'd like but we're having too many problems with people not being able to back up work, having hard drives wiped, using different computers (on the same LAN) etc.  In general most of our users would like to save to a specified location so that they can store their work on a network drive or USB key.

Open File Dialogs:  Give us a read only stream, we are not able to update the file when a user click save.

Save File Dialogs:  Do not allow us to read the already existing contests of a file / over-write the files that are selected.

Elevated Trust Mode: Doesn't work inside a browser.  Installing locally isn't an option because our users aren't administers of their machines.

Is there any way of accomplishing what we'd like that we're overlooking?

Comment: What zone is it running in. User has to trust your app not to do bad things to their file system. Elevated trust doesn't grant that.

Comment: Zone in terms of the Internet Explorer security zone?  We would be running as 'Internet'.  We could get the site added to 'Trusted sites' though if that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no.

However here are some ideas which involve changing the UI semantics which may make things more acceptable to the users.

Instead of there being "Open/Save File" of the application state use "Import/Export".  Users are more likely to accept the need to specify a file in a OpenFileDialog for import **and** to specify a file (albeit the same one) in SaveFileDialog for export.

The normal day to day state would be stored in Isolated Storage so the need to Import/Export is only invoked when the user wants to take their data to another machine.

Another option (probably in addition to the above) is to maintain a copy of the application state on the server.  Changes to the state in isolated storage are also forwarded to the server.  The isolated storage becomes more like a cache.

When the user uses another machine the state of their application is fetched from the server updating the copy in the isolated storage of the current machine.

Comment: Current what we have is an Import/Export in addition to Isolated Storage.  We've run into a lot of problems with this approach and would like to improve on it.

Comment: We also can't send information to servers due to some legal requirements.  A lot of the data is personal encrypted data, but due to some legislation even though the data is encrypted we still can't transmit it.

Comment: @Kellen: What problems have you had with import/export?  Its closest you are going to get without using OOB+ET.

Comment: We'd like users to be able to save periodically as they enter information in our application.  You can do this with import/export but it means you have to use a dialog to open the filestream when your application opens, then have an additional dialog when you want to save user info.

Comment: @Kellen: Why can't these periodic saves be performed in isolated storage?